# Are ionic 2 apps heavy with respect to storage space?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I recently started with ionic and developed a very basic app with 3 pages and a sqlite database. I checked the space it took on my phone and saw that it it's almost 8 MB. Are complex ionic apps usually heavy with respect to space?

Answer (score 0):

I have long time experience with Ionic 2 mobile applications. But I have not faced such situation like that you mentioned. Usually ionic `.apk` is very light weight and the space take for the local storage depends on your saves on the local storage. I think you have saved lot of data in your local storage. Because of that app indicates `8MB` of space takes.